# Symfony2 forms - Setting several fields using one method

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Let's say that I have an entity.

This entity has two field that should be changed only through one function, because of domain logic

How could I make the form framework to set the values using one method call.

What I've read about `data transformers`, lead me to the impression that it can not be used to this propose.

Next is `form events`, this are the available events

```
PRE_BIND    
BIND    
POST_BIND   
PRE_SET_DATA    
POST_SET_DATA   
BIND_CLIENT_DATA    
BIND_NORM_DATA  
SET_DATA
```

but the documentation about this is very scarce.

This is a sample entity

```
<?php

namespace X3\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="X3\TestBundle\Entity\TestRepository")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstValue", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstValue;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="secondValue", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $secondValue;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Test
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstValue
     *
     * @param string $firstValue
     * @return Test
     */
    protected function setFirstValue($firstValue)
    {
        $this->firstValue = $firstValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstValue
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstValue()
    {
        return $this->firstValue;
    }

    /**
     * Set secondValue
     *
     * @param string $secondValue
     * @return Test
     */
    protected function setSecondValue($secondValue)
    {
        $this->secondValue = $secondValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get secondValue
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSecondValue()
    {
        return $this->secondValue;
    }

    //
    // The objective here is that the form use this function
    // to set the two values in one call
    //
    protected function setValues($firstValue, $secondValue)
    {
        $this->firstValue = $firstValue;
        $this->secondValue = $secondValue;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Do note that `setFirstValue($firstValue)` and `setSecondValue($secondValue)` are `protected`, the values should be set using the method `setValues($firstValue, $secondValue)`

Is there an event I can use, to retrieve the `firstValue` and `secondValue` and set it using `setValues($firstValue, $secondValue)` and avoid the `form component` to complain about `Method "setFirstValue()" is not public in class...`?

Some code or link to it, would be a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the form framework would not be easy, even if using some of form events.

One possible solution would be simply create `values` property in the entity which isn't mapped to any database field, and its setter and getter. Then the `setValues` function can do whatever needed to set `firstValue` and `secondValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). It allows you to control the transformation of data in both directions. Anyway you need to add `values` field to form, that will transformed to two fields and saved as one field.

Comment: Hi thanks, any sample code, pseudo-code or link to it? It would be really appreciated.